# BottomPagerRow is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I’m using code behind from Microsoft’s FormView.BottomPagerRow Property article.  I’m getting error Object reference not set to an instance of an object on Label pageNum = (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageNumberLabel");

How do I display the pager template when there is only one record on the page?

```
protected void fvWriteUp_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int totalPages = fvWriteUp.PageCount;
    int itemCount = fvWriteUp.DataItemCount;

    // Get the pager row. From MS FormView.BottomPagerRow Property
    FormViewRow pagerRow = fvWriteUp.BottomPagerRow;

    // Get the Label controls that display the current page             information from the pager row.

    Label pageNum = 
       (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageNumberLabel");
    Label totalNum = 
       (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("TotalPagesLabel");

     if ((pageNum != null) && (totalNum != null))
     {
        // Update the Label controls with the current page values.
        int page = fvWriteUp.PageIndex + 1;
        int count = fvWriteUp.PageCount;
        pageNum.Text = page.ToString();
        totalNum.Text = count.ToString();
     }
 }
<PagerTemplate>
    <asp:Table CssClass="fvFooter" ID="RecordNav" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow
            ID="TableRow4"
            runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="recNav">
            <asp:Button ID="btnFirst" CssClass="btn btnRecNav" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" Text="First" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPrevious" CssClass="btn btnRecNav" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" Text="Previous" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnNext" CssClass="btn btnRecNav" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" Text="Next" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnLast" CssClass="btn btnRecNav" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" Text="Last" runat="server" />
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="recCounter">
            <asp:Label CssClass="lblRecs" ID="lblRecs1" runat="server" Text="Record"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label CssClass="lblRecCount" ID="PageNumberLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label CssClass="lblRecs" ID="lblRecs2" runat="server" Text="of"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label CssClass="lblRecCount" ID="TotalPagesLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table>
</PagerTemplate>
<PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" Position="Bottom" />
```

I’ve tried code like this in PreRender without luck

```
protected void fvWriteUp_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{
    FormViewRow pagerRow = fvWriteUp.BottomPagerRow;
        if (pagerRow != null && pagerRow.Visible == false)
        {
            pagerRow.Visible = true;
            fvWriteUp.BottomPagerRow.Visible = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see which object is null.

Comment: fvWriteUp.BottomPagerRow is null. pageNum is null. pagerRow is null. itemCount is 1 and totalPages is 1.

Comment: Also tried this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409173/formview-not-displaying-pagertemplate-when-only-1-item-in-datasource but it didn't work:
In the markup for the FormView I set:
AllowPaging="true"
PagerSettings-Visible="false"
Then I put all of my controls for paging in the FooterTemplate of the FormView. By doing it this way I was still able to handle all of the paging events and always have the "Pager Row" visible even when there was only one record being returned in the datasource.

Comment: Still stuck on this. In the DataBound code shown above, when fvWriteUp.PageCount and fvWriteUp.DataItem both = 1, why is fvWriteUp.BottomPagerRow null?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check for `null` on `BottomPagerRow` property for when there's no data populating your grid.

```
if (myGridView.BottomPagerRow == null)
    return;
```